# scrollIntoView affect my Listener

Tags: javascript, events, dom, scroll, ckeditor

is there a way to prevent

```
 scrollIntoView()
```

from affecting my scroll Listener i have tried

```
 evt.data.stopPropagation();
```

and

```
 elementos.scrollIntoView().stopPropagation();
```

it dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
evt.stopPropagation();
```

and

```
element.scrollIntoView();
```

*elementos.scrollIntoView().stopPropagation()* does not make any sense

Comment: im working with Ckeditor ,                                            
     evt.data.stopPropagation();
works fine but i need to exclude the event fired by my other functions